# Chrome, autofill, and biometric security

Tags: security, chrome-for-android, android-10, auto-fill

One of the recently added Android features is biometric-protected autofill. It *should* enable something similar to iOS, where credit card numbers and passwords are protected by a fingerprint or Face ID.

However, with Chrome at least, this feature seems to not work: even if biometric security is enabled, no such auth is requested when autofill login forms (ie: with password autofill).

So: is it possible to enable biometric-protected password fills in Chrome with Android 10?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the time of this writing (v87, Dec 2020), Chrome for Android doesn't support biometric-protected credential autofill.

This has been reported on Chromium Issue Tracker [#1139045 - Security Feature: Only auto-fill passwords after user provides fingerprint or PIN](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1139045#c4) on Oct 16, 2020, and acknowledged by a Chromium contributor.

> [Comment 4](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1139045#c4) by palmer@chromium.org on Tue, Oct 20, 2020, 5:36 AM GMT+7
>
> [...]
>
> we could potentially implement a feature where Chrome auto-fills passwords only after the user supplies their fingerprint or PIN. (Safari on iOS has this: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208109) I'll change this bug to a feature request.